# Is it possible to package python binary extension into wheels targeted for different hardware?

Tags: pip, hardware

Does python's `pip` allow to distribute binary extensions as separate wheels for different hardware? For instance one version for arm, another for ivybridge, another for haswell?

I know one can prepare pip package which can build itself from sources during install, but this question is about a situation when a package lacks such facility.

EDIT: I am asking from a developer/maintainer perspective.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Distributing python packages to offline machines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49635600/distributing-python-packages-to-offline-machines)

Comment: Use emulators or containers running the target OS. You can also try [cross-compilation](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bsetuptools%5D+cross-compile) but it's quite hard and not at all a popular option.

Comment: @phd I am interested in an answer from a maintainer's perspective. Right now I am working on a package which relies on a C++ library (which is part of the package) which is built as a pre-requisite with -march=native option.
I am trying to evaluate whether before I get to the point that my package would build the library itself as part of the pip installation step I would be able to pre-build wheels myself as a maintainer and allow pip to pick the right one on the client's machine.

Comment: You can (and should) prepare different wheels for different arches if they contain C extensions, e.g. `mypkg-1.0-cp36-cp36m-linux_armv7l.whl` for ARM and `mypkg-1.0-cp36-cp36m-linux_x86_64.whl` for x86_64. However, fine-tuning of `march` is not supported, so when building the extensions via `distutils`/`setuptools`, the compiler will (and should) use the generic `-march=x86-64` etc. If you need fine tuning, you should offer a source dist and the client compiles the extensions while installing; then you can adjust the compiler flags however you want, e.g. by passing `-march=native`.

Comment: @hoefling thank you, this answers my question.